# bash: 'command not found' for python, r and nano

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, development-environment

On `git bash`, I receive a `command not found` message for `python`, `r` and `nano`.

I am on Windows 10. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I type

```
r --version
python --version
nano --version
```

and they all return `command not found`.

I read something that had me try

```
alias python='winpty python.exe'
```

and it renamed `python`, but when I tried

```
touch .bashrc
```

it returned

> touch: command not found

I followed the instructions in a Github course, PS239T. I have been fortunate, except for getting these three programs to work.

I tried

```
build/console.exe c:/Python36/python.exe
```

and it returned

> build/console.exe: No such file or directory

I tried

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/Python36/
```

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python36"
```

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python36"' > .profile
```

and nothing.

I got Python 64-bit via Anaconda.

I tried setting up the Python 3.4 environment

```
conda create –n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

```
./python name_of_your_python_script.py
```

nothing.

```
which python
```

got me a huge directory path:

```
which: no python in (/c/Users/Edward/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:usr
/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:c/user/Edward/bin:/c/Program Files
(X86)/Intel/ 1CLS client:/c/Program Files/Intel/1CLS Client:/c/Windows
/System32:/C/Windows:/C/Windows/Sytem32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32
WindowsPowerShell/V1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
Components/Dal:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) magament Engine
Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (X86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
Components/IPT:/c/WINDOWS/Syste,32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32
/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files (x86)/Rand McNally/RNDDock
/GtkSharp/2.12/bin/:/c/Program Files d/AppData/Local/Mircosoft
/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Edward/AppData/Local/Pandoc:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:
/usr/bincore_perl:/c/python36
```

I would have just put up the screenshot or copied and pasted it, but I do not know how.

I am sure I made an error somewhere.

I get the same type of results when I try to figure out what is going on with `r` and `nano`.

## Update 1

> Download and install 'Anaconda'

```
'https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/'.
```

> Download the default Python 3 installer 'do not follow the link to version 2'.
>   Use all of the defaults for installation except make sure to check 'Make Anaconda the default Python.'
>
> Install R by downloading and running

```
'this .exe file from CRAN'  

'http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/release.htm'.
```

> Also, please install the 'RStudio IDE'

```
'http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/desktop'.
```

All you need is RStudio Desktop.

> nano is a basic editor and the default that we use in this class. To install 
>   it, download the `Software Carpentry Windows installer`

```
http://files.software-carpentry.org/SWCarpentryInstaller.exe'
```

> and double click on the file to run it. 'This installer requires an active internet connection.'
>
> Sublime Text is a more advanced editor. Download Sublime Text 3 'here'

```
'https://www.sublimetext.com/3'.
```

## Update 2

I began trying janos advice and ran

```
/c/Python36/python.exe --version
```

and it returned

> bash: '/c/python36/python.exe: No such file or directory.

I tried to run

```
PATH="/c/Python36:$PATH" python.exe --version
```

but it returned

> bash: python.exe.: command not found

I tried to run

```
PATH="/c/Python36:$PATH" python --version
```

and it returned

> bash: python: command not found

## Update 3

janos told me I went too far without figuring out the problem, then told me to run

```
ls -l /c/Python36/python.exe
```

and it returned

> ls: cannot access '/c/Python36/python.exe': no such file or directory.

janos told me to focus on the first error

> bash: '/c/python36/python.exe: No such file or directory.

after entering

```
/c/Python36/python.exe --version
```

and so there I will focus.

janos asserted

> Can you open a file explorer and navigate to C:\Python36, and see python.exe there? Probably not.

and is correct.

I ran

```
C/Users/Edward/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.3-h9e2ca53_1/python.exe
```

with no success.

I ran that in explorer and found that the publisher could not be verified.

## Update 4

I went to

```
'python.org/downloads/release/python-363'
```

and downloaded 'Windows x86 embeddable zip file' and Unzipped it in

```
C/Users/Edward/Anaconda3/pkgs
```

it worked.

Thank you.

I bet I am having the same problems with 'r' and 'nano'.

I am going to run down the list again and perform all the check. I will do the same thing with 'r' and 'nano'.

Everything worked out for Python. I will do 'nano' and 'r' in due course.

I could not find

```
/c/python36/
```

so I used

```
/c/Users/Edward/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.3-embed-win32/
```

## Update 5

janos is right again. I would need to create the python36 folder as it was not built automatically during the installation. janos' method worked on 'r' and 'subl' or sublime text 3. I gave up on 'nano'.

I found that some of my '.exe' files were in listing with spaces in the names. I moved to the user folder and eliminated any spaces.

I also downloaded version from the official website, and that too helped.

I could not figure out how to get 'nano' to work. I could not even find it on my pc. I used 'subl' instead.

Comment: Great that it's solved. Notice how I added the **Update** section headings. Try to do that in the future so that it's easier for others, including the kind answerer helping you, to understand your progress. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from the basics. Try the simplest thing that can possibly work,
and make progress in baby steps,
from one sane state to the next.

The first step is to run a by entering its absolute path directly.
If the Python executable is at `/c/Python36/python.exe`, then run this:

```
/c/Python36/python.exe --version
```

This is very simple and it should just work.
If it doesn't, the command will give you an error message with clues.

A next step could be to *simulate* adding to `PATH`. Try this:

```
PATH="/c/Python36:$PATH" python.exe --version
```

This is one line. It sets a value to `PATH` in a way such that it's only active during the execution of the command. After the command completes, the value of `PATH` will be back to what it was before. This is a good way to test things. Also notice that I *prepended* to `PATH` the directory that contains `python.exe`, not the full path to `python.exe`.
That's an important point, this is how the `PATH` variable works.
It's a list of directories, and all executable files in those directories become easily executable by simply typing their name, without having to type their absolute paths.

Next, I would try this:

```
PATH="/c/Python36:$PATH" python --version
```

That is, see if you can drop the `.exe` from the name of the command.
I don't have Windows so I cannot test if this works.
And maybe it doesn't. (But I think it does.)

If everything worked so far, then the next step is to make the `PATH` setting permanent.
The way to do that is to put the command `PATH="/c/Python36:$PATH"` into a file that is always executed when you start a new Git Bash session.
If I remember correctly on Windows you can put it in `~/.profile`
(a file named `.profile` in your home directory).
Where is `~`? Here's one way to find it:

```
cd
explorer .
```

The above opens a file manager inside that directory.
You can use a plain-text editor like Notepad or Wordpad to edit it.
You can also use this shell command to append the line that updates `PATH`:

```
echo 'PATH="/c/Python36:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

This line will get executed in all new Git Bash session.
Not in the current session,
because this file is only executed once.

If everything above worked, then in a new Git Bash session you should be able to run `python --version`.
If not everything worked, then you need to read the error message you get carefully, and not advance to the next step until the problem is resolved.
It's useless to advance to a next step when you are already not in a sane state.

You can follow the exact same logical process for all the other programs too.

Comment: Legend - this worked!
The solution for me was to try
`/c/anaconda3/python.exe --version`
and then add this to my profile using...

`cd C:/`, then
`echo 'PATH="/c/anaconda3:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile`.

After restarting Git Bash, `python --version` worked first time :)