# Bash not calling nano

Tags: bash, nano

I decided to try to get the nano editor to work on my 'git bash' and failed. 'r' 'python' 'git' 'subl' 'pandoc' and 'pdflatex' all work thanks to advising I got from janos here:

> [On git bash, command not found for python, r and nano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482872/on-git-bash-command-not-found-for-python-r-and-nano)

I figure I should learn how to get nano to work as well. I feel like I got close, but could not figure out the problem.

```
PATH="/c/Users/Edward/nano-2.4.2/nano-2.4.2-win32:$PATH" nano --version
```

and

```
echo 'PATH="/c/Users/Edward/nano-2.4.2/nano-2.4.2-win32:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

work, but

```
nano --version
```

does not work.

Comment: Can you run `echo $PATH` to see if your new path includes the nano directory? You'll need to source `.profile` or logout and back in for this to take effect.

Comment: 'bash' does not include it in the directory. Although it us in my .profile.

Comment: Could you post an output of `cat ~/.profile`? You may have some extra junk in there that is messing with your path. You can use any text editor to clean it up if necessary. Could you also post the error message you get when running `nano --version`?

Comment: Did you login again, or run `bash -l` before trying to . run `nano`, or use `. ~/.profile` to reexecute (reread) your profile?  If not, you need to do one of those.

Comment: @John Moon  

I tried it the other day, and it did not show up. Today. It does. I do not know what happened.  

    PATH="/c/Users/Edward/R-3.4.2/bin:$PATH"PATH="/c/Users/Edward/SublimeText3:$PATH"PATH="/c/Users/Edward/nano-2.4.2/nano-2.4.2-win32:$PATH"

Comment: >bash: nano: command not found

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  

They did not work.  

  nano --version  

still returns  

>bash: nano: command not found

Comment: 'Where nano' returns the exact path to 'nano' all the way down to 'nano.exe'